# What is the problem with pictures?

Tags: graphics, packages, diagrams, pdf, input

The code is worked with no problems but the picture can't be uploaded in the pdf and I don't know whay?

```
\documentclass[AMA,LATO1COL]{WileyNJD-v2}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{pbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centerline{\includegraphics[width=20pc,height=15pc,draft]{ZVC-Galactic-_1.png}}
\caption{zvc of the galactic system for $h = 0.024.$}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does "draft" not mean that images are not imported?

Comment: yes I know but when I delete it this error shown up   :   ! Package pdftex.def Error: File `ZVC-N4-1-3.png' not found: using draft setting.See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... ...[width=20pc,height=15pc]{ZVC-N4-1-3.png}}

Comment: Is it relevant that the image name in your MWE is `ZVC-Galactic-_1.png` but in the error message is `ZVC-N4-1-3.png` ? If not, are the images in the same folder as your .tex file? Also, I think it's generally not advisable to have symbols in names (anything other than A-Z, a-z, 0-9).

Answer (score 1):

> this error shown up : ! Package pdftex.def Error: File
> `ZVC-N4-1-3.png' not found:

Can it be that you have your graphics in a separate directory, say img/? If so, this should resolve it: `\includegraphics[width=20pc,height=15pc]{img/ZVC-Galactic-_1.png}` (Please notice the new file name.)